# Find subgraph with maximum number of edges

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose there is a simple graph G. Is there a way to find a subgraph with a maximum of edges, for a certain number of vertices m?

Comment: I'm guessing such an algorithm is not known. Otherwise you would be able to find a maximal clique in the graph which is NP hard.

Comment: No, for fixed $k$ the problem is not NP-hard and there is an obvious polynomial-time algorithm to solve it.

Comment: @MJD Can you give the algorithm please?

Comment: Examine all $\binom vk$ $k$-tuples of vertices and count which  set has the most edges.